# Find the most popular word order in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to find the most common word order in a pandas dataframe for strings which occur more than once.

**Example Dataframe**

```
                                         title
0                             Men's Nike Socks
1                             Nike Socks Men's
2                       Men's Black Nike Socks
3                             Men's Nike Socks
4  Everyday 3 Pack Cotton Cushioned Crew Socks
```

**Desired Output**

> Men's Nike Socks

This is because each word occurs more than once, arranged in the most common order.

**What I've Tried**

I thought one way to tackle this is to assign a score for each word position, e.g. first position = high score, a low position (further right in the sentence = lower score).

I considered counting the maximum number of words which appear in the dataframe and then use that to incrementally score the words based on their frequency and position.

I Python beginner and not sure how to progress further than that.

It's worth mentioning that the word sizes will be random, and not constrained to the example above.

**Minimum Reproducible Example**

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    "Men's Nike Socks for sale",
    "Nike Socks Men's",
    "Men's Nike Socks in the UK",
    "Men's Nike Socks to buy",
    "Everyday 3 Pack Cotton Cushioned Crew Socks",
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['title'])

print(df)
```

Edit: My original example is too simplified as my desired output appeared twice exactly in the dataframe.

I've updated the dataframe, but the desired output is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [value_counts()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [idxmax()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html).

```
result = df['title'].value_counts().idxmax()
print(result)
```

Output: `Men's Nike Socks`

*Explanation:*

```
>>> df['title'].value_counts()

Men's Nike Socks                               2
Nike Socks Men's                               1
Men's Black Nike Socks                         1
Everyday 3 Pack Cotton Cushioned Crew Socks    1
Name: title, dtype: int64
```

Update base new DataFrame:

```
max_split = df['title'].str.split().apply(len).max()
for i in range(1, max_split):
    try:
        result = df['title'].str.split(' ', i, expand=True).iloc[:, :-1].apply(' '.join, axis=1).mode()[0]
    except TypeError:
        break
print(result)
```

Output: `Men's Nike Socks`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works because I included the same string twice in my dataframe. 

In practice this may not be the case, although it returns the right answer for my example.

This is why I envisioned scoring each word individually by it's position and frequency. 

Would it be better to edit my example?

Comment: @LeeRoy, If this is OK, I understanded your example and don't need to edit.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate the answer, but I've updated the sample dataframe as the data was simple to the point I think I confused what I'm looking for.

The desired output is the same, but I've tweaked the source data to be more reflective of real world data. Thanks again.

Comment: @LeeRoy, Edited the answer, Is this helping you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`pandas.Series.mode`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html?highlight=mode#pandas.Series.mode) that returns the most frequent value in a column/serie :

```
out = df['title'].mode()
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

0    Men's Nike Socks
Name: title, dtype: object
```

##### # Edit :

To find the most frequent phrases in a column, use [**`nltk`**](https://www.nltk.org/) as shown in the code below (highly inspired by @[jezarel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael)) :

```
from nltk import ngrams

vals = [y for x in df['title'] for y in x.split()]
n = [3, 4, 5] # Phrases between 3 and 5 words, To be adjusted !

out = pd.Series([' '.join(y) for x in n for y in ngrams(vals, x)]).value_counts().idxmax()


print(out)
Men's Nike Socks
```

Comment: Really appreciate the answer. My source dataframe was a little confusing as I over simplified it and it contained my desired output exactly, twice. So it's easy to get value counts etc which is not what I was looing for unfortunately. (My fault!).

I've updated the question so it's more reflective of the real word data. Really appreciate you taking the time to answer.